# Angular url param is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, undefined, url-parameters

I am trying to get url parameter value but it is undefined and I don't find why...

Code

```js
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.params['lang']);
  }
}
```

URL

`localhost:4200/home?lang=EN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `queryParams` not `params`.

`params` is for `myRoute/mySubRoute/:myParam:/`

`queryParams` is for `myRoute/mySubRoute?param=value` where `?param=value` is the `queryString`.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParams['lang']);
  }
}
```